# TypeScript's "Combine JavaScript output into file" option doesn't infer correct script order without /// <reference> tags

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript solution that uses the "Combine JavaScript output into file" option:

[image]

I'll often reference an item defined in another file, for example:

In `MyBaseClass.ts`:

```
export class MyBaseClass { }
```

In `MySubClass.ts`:

```
export class MySubClass extends MyBaseClass { }
```

While developing, Visual Studio has no problem understanding that `MySubClass` references the `MyBaseClass` defined in `MyBaseClass.ts` - the solution successfully builds and I can navigate to `MyBaseClass` using <kbd>F12</kbd>.

However, I run into runtime errors when I run the solution because the generated JavaScript file defines `MySubClass` before `MyBaseClass`.

I can fix these runtime errors by adding a `/// <reference>` tag in `MySubClass.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="MyBaseClass.ts" />
export class MySubClass extends MyBaseClass { }
```

**Why does the IDE understand the relationship between `MySubClass` and `MyBaseClass`, but the compiler doesn't correctly order the definitions of these classes in the generated output?**

I'd either like the generated output to correctly infer the order of the class definitions (preferred) or the TypeScript compiler to throw errors if the `/// <reference>` tags aren't present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the IDE understand the relationship between MySubClass and MyBaseClass,

It only knows the semantic relationship. Not the runtime requirements. How you do the module loading is *up to you*.

Note: https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#reference and https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#javascript-generation

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In my case, wouldn't "module loading" be conceptually synonymous with the automatic generation of the single JavaScript file?  If so, it's *not* up to me.

Also, I'm not sure your links are applicable in my situation - I'm using a stock install of Visual Studio 2014 for my TypeScript compilation/combination, not node.js/grunt.  Unless Visual Studio uses the `grunt-ts` plugin under the hood?

Comment: `In my case, wouldn't "module loading" be conceptually synonymous with the automatic generation of the single JavaScript file?` It could do it. But it doesn't do it. So it is up to you. Sorry. Its a gotcha.

Comment: Hmm, that is a gotcha.  I'm trying to pitch TypeScript to other members of my team, and details like this don't help my case.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Best that you use external modules / commonjs.  This is where JavaScript at scale is going anyways. There the module loading order is managed by the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I really whish this could be fixed. Typescript intellisense does not seem to have any problem at all infering the proper order. When the compiler, which has the option "Combine into one file" does not solve this, it renders larger js files upfront unreliable ... 
The normal response to this issue is, use dynamic loading ... that is true. But in my case, the modules which are dynamically loaded, already exist of many classes which are in seperate projects compiled into a single file. Hence the problem exists in that scenario as well ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is now possible with TypeScript 1.8:

https://medium.com/@vivainio/with-latest-typescript-you-may-not-need-webpack-417d2ef0e773#.tcu41xsft

You need to make sure System or AMD module system is selected:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile