# Typescript Visual Studios 2015 auto compile bug

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2015 and have enabled auto compile on save.

In the compiled js file, I'm getting an error in the typescript __extends function where 'Cannot read property prototype of undefined' for b.prototype.

However, whenever I rebuild the project, the error goes away and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds to me like an issue with the order in which your classes are being inserted into your compiled `.js` file.  [I had a similar problem with Visual Studio's single-file compilation functionality.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481684/typescripts-combine-javascript-output-into-file-option-doesnt-infer-correct)  As you look through the compiled file, is there any class that inherits from a base class that isn't defined until later in the file?

I'm not sure why the behavior only shows up when the compilation is trigger by a save - that seems weird to me.  Sometimes the compiler seems kind of non-deterministic when it has to guess at the order in which to output results.  This might have something to do with incremental compilation?

To fix this, you can tell the compiler that a particular class should be defined after another with a `<reference>` tag.

So, for example, a subclass with a reference tag like this:

```
/// <reference path="./MyBaseClass" />
class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {
}
```

will appear *after* the following class in the compiled `.js` file:

```
class MyBaseClass {
}
```